# How to print list of lists without extra brackets and quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on assignment for my Python 3 programming class. It's a database to look up movies and the year they came out. However, I'm having a hard time printing the output without extra brackets and quotes:

```
# Build a dictionary containing the specified movie collection
list_2005 = [["Munich", "Steven Spielberg"]]
list_2006 = [["The Departed", "Martin Scorsese"], ["The Prestige", "Christopher Nolan"]]
list_2007 = [["Into the Wild", "Sean Penn"]]

movies = {
'2005': list_2005, 
'2006': list_2006, 
'2007': list_2007
      }

# Prompt the user for a year 
# Displaying the title(s) and directors(s) from that year
user_year = str(input("Enter a year between 2005 and 2007:\n"))

if user_year in movies:

    for name in movies[user_year]:
        print("%s" % ', '.join(name))
    print()

elif user_year not in movies:
    print("N/A")

# Display menu
user_choice = ''

while user_choice != 'q':
    print("MENU\nSort by:\ny - Year\nd - Director\nt - Movie title\nq - Quit")
    print()
    user_choice = str(input("Choose an option:\n"))

    if user_choice == 'y':
       for key, value in sorted(movies.items()):
           print("%s:" % key)
           print("    %s" % ''.join(str(movies[key])))


# Carry out the desired option: Display movies by year, 
# display movies by director, display movies by movie title, or quit
```

I would like this output to be:

```
2005:
    Munich, Steven Spielberg

2006:
    The Prestige, Christopher Nolan
    The Departed, Martin Scorsese
```

etc.

The output I am getting:

```
2005:
    ['Munich', 'Steven Spielberg']

2006:
    [['The Prestige', 'Christopher Nolan'], ['The Departed', 'Martin Scorsese']]
```

etc.

Comment: each value printed is on a separate line, not bunched together

Comment: It would make your life easier if you used better names than `key` and `value`, e.g. `year` and `movies`. To get the desired output, don't just print the list of films converted to a string. You need an additional `for` loop over the individual movies, then print the title and the director in each iteration.

Comment: You did it correctly at the top of your program, just do it the same way at the bottom.

Comment: you don't need `"%s" % ` to print it - use `print(', '.join(name))`

Comment: in python3 `input()` always returns string so you don't need `str()` - use directly `user_choice = input("Choose an option:\n")`

Comment: Hint: `print(['foo'], ['bar'])` prints `['foo'], ['bar']`. To print `foo, bar` you need to fetch items from each list and print the individual items.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
print(" %s" % ''.join(str(movies[key])))
```

with

```
print("\t" + '\n\t'.join("{}, {}".format(m[0], m[1]) for m in movies[key]))
```

Comment: If this resolved the issue, you may want to accept it as the answer